# Spring cloud streams - multiple routing functions in multimodule project creates output bindings

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

We've got a multi-module project which needs multiple routing functions (our case is that we're developing modular-monolithic application and we need to consume one message in multiple modules). The problem is that routing functions creates *-out-0 topics in message broker, but in our case **we've got only routing to consumers** (not to another functions). Documentation says that

> We never create output binding for the `RoutingFunction`, only input. So when you routing to `Consumer`, the `RoutingFunction` effectively
> becomes as a `Consumer` by not having any output bindings. However, if `RoutingFunction` happen to route to another `Function` which produces
> the output, the output binding for the `RoutingFunction` will be create dynamically at which point `RoutingFunction` will act as a regular `Function`
> with regards to bindings (having both input and output bindings)

(https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/commit/b2b95dc7d292578c56ae42b066f437b0f1436e65)

In above commit you can see that there's if statement condition added in line 806 in FunctionConfiguration which checks if functionDefinition has default function name (`functionRouter`).

We're using spring-cloud-stream in version 3.2.4

In payload of message we've got custom header which tells what's the type of object in payload (e.g. DocumentCreatedEvent, DocumentFinishedEvent) and consumers:

```
class DocumentCreatedEventConsumer implements Consumer<DocumentCreatedEvent> {
    @Override
    void accept(final DocumentCreatedEvent event) {
        // do something here...
    }
}

class DocumentFinishedEventConsumer implements Consumer<DocumentFinishedEvent> {
    @Override
    void accept(final DocumentFinishedEvent event) {
        // do something here...
    }
}
```

which are registered as beans:

```
@Bean
Consumer<DocumentCreatedEvent> firstModuleDocumentCreatedEventConsumer() {
    return new DocumentCreatedEventConsumer();
}

@Bean
Consumer<DocumentCreatedEvent> secondModuleDocumentCreatedEventConsumer() {
    return new DocumentCreatedEventConsumer();
}

@Bean
Consumer<DocumentFinishedEvent> firstModuleDocumentFinishedEventConsumer() {
    return new DocumentFinishedEventConsumer();
}

@Bean
Consumer<DocumentFinishedEvent> secondModuleDocumentFinishedEventConsumer() {
    return new DocumentFinishedEventConsumer();
}
```

Our yaml fragment is as below:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      autodetect: false
      routing.enabled: true
      definition: firstModuleRouter;secondModuleRouter
    stream:
      bindings:
        firstModuleRouter-in-0:
          destination: output-topic
        secondModuleRouter-in-0:
          destination: output-topic
```

Our bean which register routing functions:

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class RegisterMessageBrokerRouters {
    private final ConfigurableListableBeanFactory configurableListableBeanFactory;
    private final FunctionCatalog functionCatalog;
    private final FunctionProperties functionProperties;
    private final BindingServiceProperties bindingServiceProperties;

    @PostConstruct
    void registerRouters() {
        bindingServiceProperties.getBindings().keySet().stream()
            .filter(it -> it.contains("Router-in-"))
            .map(it -> it.replaceAll("Router-in-\\d+", ""))
            .forEach(module -> {
                final String beanName = module + "Router";
                configurableListableBeanFactory.registerSingleton(beanName, createRoutingFunction(module));
                log.info("Registered bean '" + beanName + "' for module: " + module);
            });
    }

    private RoutingFunction createRoutingFunction(final String moduleName) {
        return new RoutingFunction(functionCatalog, functionProperties, new BeanFactoryResolver(configurableListableBeanFactory),
            new ConsumerMessageRoutingCallback(functionCatalog, moduleName));
    }
}
```

Above code register routing functions: **firstModuleRouter** and **secondModuleRouter**

Our ConsumerMessageRoutingCallback class:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ConsumerMessageRoutingCallback implements MessageRoutingCallback {
    private static final String CONSUMER_SUFFIX = "Consumer";
    private static final String DEFAULT_MESSAGE_ROUTING_HANDLER_NAME = "defaultMessageRoutingHandler";
    private final FunctionCatalog functionCatalog;
    private final String moduleName;

    @Override
    public FunctionRoutingResult routingResult(final Message<?> message) {
        final Object contentTypeHeader = message.getHeaders().get(MessagingHeaders.PAYLOAD_TYPE);
        if (contentTypeHeader != null) {
            return new FunctionRoutingResult(route(contentTypeHeader.toString()));
        }
        return new FunctionRoutingResult(DEFAULT_MESSAGE_ROUTING_HANDLER_NAME);
    }

    String route(final String qualifiedPayloadType) {
        final String expectedBeanName = buildExpectedBeanName(moduleName, qualifiedPayloadType);
        return beanExists(expectedBeanName) ? expectedBeanName : DEFAULT_MESSAGE_ROUTING_HANDLER_NAME;
    }

    private String buildExpectedBeanName(final String moduleName, final String qualifiedPayloadType) {
        return replaceFirstLetterToLowerCase(nullable(moduleName) + simpleClassName(qualifiedPayloadType) + CONSUMER_SUFFIX);
    }

    private String replaceFirstLetterToLowerCase(final String input) {
        return input.substring(0, 1).toLowerCase() + input.substring(1);
    }

    private String nullable(final String value) {
        return StringUtils.isNotBlank(value) ? value : "";
    }

    private String simpleClassName(final String fullClassName) {
        return fullClassName.substring(fullClassName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
    }

    private boolean beanExists(final String expectedCallMethod) {
        return functionCatalog.lookup(expectedCallMethod) != null;
    }
}
```

In this case spring-cloud-stream create's output binding (and topics in message broker) which are not used:

- firstModuleRouter-out-0
- secondModuleRouter-out-0

So the question is: **is there any way to disable creating of output bindings from routing functions?** We've checked sources of spring-cloud-stream and we didn't find any way to do this.

As a workaround we've found the solution to forward created output bindings to output-topic as defined in yaml:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      autodetect: false
      routing.enabled: true
      definition: firstModuleRouter;secondModuleRouter
    stream:
      bindings:
        firstModuleRouter-in-0:
          destination: output-topic
        firstModuleRouter-out-0:
          destination: output-topic
        secondModuleRouter-in-0:
          destination: output-topic
        secondModuleRouter-out-0:
          destination: output-topic
```

But we believe there should be any other solution to disable creating of additional topics in message broker.

Answer (score 0):

I already have met that problem. We have solved it by taking the rights for creating topics on kafka side, and yes it is bad solution, but still.. ))

Comment: Thanks for your response. We've already considered this as workaround (I've found it before I ask this question), but we believe there should be a way to configure it via framework.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved in Spring Cloud Stream 4.0.1. It was reported at GitHub https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2590.